# Group by date every 10 days

Tags: mysql, sql, date, group-by

I have this scheme:

```
+----+--+--------+--------------------+
| ID |   Amount  |      paydate       |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 |    200    |2016-11-05          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+ 
|  2 |    3000   |2016-11-10          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+ 
|  3 |   2500    |2016-11-11          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+ 
| ID |   100     |2016-11-21          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
|  1 |    200    |2016-11-22          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+ 
|  2 |    3000   |2016-11-23          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+ 
|  3 |   2500    |2016-11-29          |
+----+-----------+--------------------+
```

How can I get the total Amount grouped by every 10 days  like  from the first of every month to the 10th then from 11th to 20th and from 21st to the end of the month?

to be shown like this :

```
+-----------+------------------------+
|   Amount  |      paydate           |
+-----------+------------------------+ 
|    3200   |2016-11-1 to 2016-11-10 |
+-----------+------------------------+ 
|    2500   |2016-11-11 to 2016-11-20|
+-----------+------------------------+ 
|   5800    |2016-11-21 to 2016-11-31|     
+-----------+------------------------+
```

I tried

```
SELECT 
    SUM(Amount) AS Amount, 
    year(Facture.paydate) AS Annee, 
    month(Facture.paydate) AS Mois 
FROM Facture 
GROUP BY year(Facture.paydate), month(serFacture.paydate)
```

but this does not give me the result I need.

Comment: Add a few October dates, and perhaps some 2015 dates.

Comment: Use a calendar table, I.e. a table containing the dates you want. Then join on it and group by.

Comment: @Ben  How ? can u please give an example

Comment: ID?? Are you sure??

Comment: @Strawberry that was a mistake  thank u

Comment: If only there was some kind of edit button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select      sum(Amount) as sum_amount
           ,case 
                when day(paydate) <= 10 then concat(DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-01'),' to ',DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-10'))
                when day(paydate) <= 20 then concat(DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-11'),' to ',DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-20'))
                else concat(DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-21'),' to ',DATE_FORMAT(paydate,'%Y-%m-31'))
            end as paydate_period

from        t

group by    paydate_period
;
```

---

```
sum_amount  paydate_period
3200        2016-11-01 to 2016-11-10
2500        2016-11-11 to 2016-11-20
5800        2016-11-21 to 2016-11-31
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example query:

```
select 
case 
    when day(date_field) between 1 and 10 then "01 to 10"
    when day(date_field) between 11 and 20 then "11 to 20"
    when day(date_field) between 21 and 31 then "21 to 31"
end as the_range,
date_format(date_field, "%m%Y") as the_month,
count(*) 
from 
the_table
group by 
the_range, the_month
order by
the_month, the_range;
```

You can adapt the query so you display your result the way you need.